# Difference between $('div div') and $('div').find('div')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find

I was just poking around with jQuery, and I stumbled upon the Find function.

I tested like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){

        $('div').find('div').fadeOut(2000);

    });
});
```

And this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){

        $('div div').fadeOut(2000);

    });
});
```

And both produce the exact same result.

Whats the difference? :)

Comment: According to the functional spec, there should not be any difference at all. There is possibly some performance difference, which should be negligible.

Comment: @Jon Well, the latter is easier to type out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example there is no difference but there are cases that you can not use the first one, for example let't say you have an element as the parameter of a function and you want to find divs inside it, then you have to use the "Find" method.

```
function foo(index, el)
{
    $(el).find("div")...
}
```

But when you know the exact path, obviously the second approach is more robus.

Comment: @Jeff: Only if `el` is a selector.

Comment: @vali: That's only for `.find`, not for other selectors.

Comment: @valipour - That does not work when you do $(el,'div') - it will affect the `el` too :)

Comment: @Jeff: have never tried that one, but I believe they all must be deprecated now. There are numerous chainable tree traversal methods that are more readable. See here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

If you already have a jQuery object, the `find` method is useful.
Otherwise, a single selector is simpler.

Most selectors have method equivalents (`.children()`, `.first()`, `.not()`) for this reason.

The method versions also allow you to call [`.end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) to go back to the previous object.

Comment: nice, I didn't know about .end(), but isn't it too much chaining? using this will make the code horribly unreadable :)

Answer (score 1):

They both do exactly the same thing, but in older browsers where `document.querySelectorAll()` is not available (Old IEs) `$("div").find("div");` is quicker, as Paul Irish confirms in [this comment here](http://paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/#comment-33704).

Another thing to note is that in jQuery you can also do this:

```
$("div", "#some-element")
```

Which would search for `div` inside of `#some-element`. jQuery actually converts this into:

```
$("#some-element").find("div")
```

So it's always suggested to use .find() rather than pass in a context.

Comment: +1 This is true. On the other hand, browsers *with* qSA will be much quicker with `div div`.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, they do the same thing. Note that `find()` will traverse **all** the descendants of the matched elements.

Comment: Yes, in this specific case. I was noting the general functionality of `find()`